# Get actual href used in document instead of full path?

Tags: javascript

```
<a href='/a01'></a>
```

If I were to check .href of that using javascript, it would give the full path, instead of /a01.

Using getAttribute does return the full path, however it is much slower than .href. Is there a fast way to get the actual href?

Comment: What's `much slower`? Unless you're doing this hundreds/thousands of times on a page over prolonged periods, then what's a few extra milliseconds?

Comment: @MarcB, I am doing this thousands of times on a page. :( It's an emote userscript. Currently I'm using pathname, but as http://jsfiddle.net/CkLrz/ shows, it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: IE won't necessarily return the actual href attribute value with *getAttribute*, it will return the full path. It's one of the inconsistencies with get/setAttribute across browsers. Direct property access is more consistent and therefore generally preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're saying  that you only want the path, then use the `.pathname` property instead of the `.href` property.

There are also `.search` and `.hash` for the querystring and hash tag. There are a number of others as well.

---

Another option is...

```
elem.attributes['href'].value;
```

...but I'd be surprised if it was quicker. I'm not certain of browser compatibility issues either.

And another few...

```
elem.attributes.getNamedItem('href').value;
elem.attributes.item('href').value;
elem.getAttributeNode('href').value
```

If the `.value` property gives you trouble in older browsers, try `nodeValue`.

Comment: I'm afraid that this doesn't work. It then gives /a01 even if a full link was used in the href. http://jsfiddle.net/CkLrz/

Comment: @nallar: Wasn't sure what you were ultimately after. If you want the actual value of the attribute, then you'll need `getAttribute()`. There are other ways to get at it using the `.attributes` property, but I doubt they will be any quicker *(and are actually probably slower)*.

Comment: make that an answer, I'll check with jsperf tomorrow when I have time in case it is faster, as it's possible that it will be. Even if it's only faster on one browser, that'd still be useful to know.

Comment: @nallar: Already updated. There's a couple different ways to work with `.attributes`. If I can recall more of the API, I'll update again.

Comment: It seems that I did something wrong previously when I tested .getAttribute, it's faster than .href. Modified the previous jsperf to add it. Sorry for wasting your time, and that of others answering.

Comment: @nallar: [Moving `getElementById` out of the test cases](http://jsperf.com/href-attribute-get/2) is better IMO. But why don't you complain? It seems that `getAtribute()` is even faster than `href`. *edit:* I was too slow :D

Comment: Yeah, it's `getAttribute` is faster than `href` also for me, on MacBook Air. :)

Comment: @FelixKling—using *getAttribute* won't return the actual attribute value in IE (<9 at least).

Answer (score 1):

> Using getAttribute does return the full path

I assume you meant that does return the actual href instead of the full path; because that's exactly what it's supposed to be used to get that value.

You can always playing with properties of a link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement

And then using [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) properties, extract the relative part of the url, however this is not return the *actual* href value attribute, but just the relative one, and I don't know if it's worthy – it's much less readable and error prone.

I wonder which kind of performance issue you have for using `getAttribute` in this case.

Comment: `getAttribute('href')` **does not** return the *href* attribute value in IE<9, it returns the *href* property value instead.

Comment: without any specific browsers indication in the questions, I'm always talking in term of web standards; but it's a good point.

Comment: Supporting web standards is great, but you must also deal with reality. IE<9 represents at least 25% of browsers on the web. Answers should be in terms of the most compatible approach, which should address not just standards, but what will work for the greatest number of browsers.

Comment: There is no need to add complexity if is not required, IMVHO. The OP itself didn't raise the problem about IE<9, it means that in his case is not probably an issue – maybe it is an extension, or a web app that doesn't support old browsers versions, or it's an intranet app. So, it's good to mention this issue, but if the question itself doesn't indicate any specific browsers to support I just going with the standards. If the question gives a context, of course, it's a different matter.

Comment: Just because a poster doesn't raise a really obvious issue (like a quarter of browsers not supporting whatever it is you're recommending as a solution) doesn't mean it shouldn't be addressed. Everyone has *unknown unknowns*. You should always qualify generalisations where they are not true a good percentage of the time (and therefore shouldn't be generalisations because they aren't generally true).

Comment: It's "obvious" depends by the context, that wasn't provided. What I described is how I handle the questions, it doesn't means everyone should do the same. :)