# get string inside the src attribute not the absolute path

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a video tag like this:

```
<video id="video-upload-preview" controls="" src="/admin/session/trimed/trimmed.mp4"></video>
```

and I want the string inside `src` so I did this:

```
document.getElementById('video-upload-preview').src
```

But the result is something else, it's the absolute path to the source not the actual string:

> 'https://www.example.com/admin/session/trimed/trimmed.mp4'

Is there any way to get only the string inside `src` attribute?

The desired result would be:

> /admin/session/trimed/trimmed.mp4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get actual href used in document instead of full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660834/get-actual-href-used-in-document-instead-of-full-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function removeSubStr(){
    let domain = "https://stacksnippets.net"; // Here put "https://www.example.com"
    let str = document.getElementById("video-upload-preview")
                      .src.replace( domain, "" );
    document.getElementById("url").textContent = str;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="video-upload-preview" controls="" src="/admin/session/trimed/trimmed.mp4"></video>
        <p id="url">Click button</p>
        <button onClick="removeSubStr()">Click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a shorter way.

```
document.getElementById('video-upload-preview').attributes.getNamedItem('src').value;
```

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660834/get-actual-href-used-in-document-instead-of-full-path